# Application deployment failed using Jboss 6.4 and IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, jboss6.x

I have added JBOSS 6.4 to IntelliJ IDE.I could not access the port 8080 of JBOSS even the sever is up. It appears that the deployment has some problems, but I couldn't able to find out what's wrong here.Somehow the deployment is getting stopped.Here is the complete log file. Please let me know if you need any additional information to find the issue.

```
D:\jboss-eap-6.4.0\jboss-eap-6.4\bin\standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.7\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.7\lib\util.jar" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\dt76747\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath0.tmp com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 59767 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss71Agent
[2017-07-21 04:21:25,981] Artifact csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 9999
Detected server http port: 8080
Calling "D:\jboss-eap-6.4.0\jboss-eap-6.4\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -server -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m "
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\jboss-eap-6.4.0\jboss-eap-6.4"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -server -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

===============================================================================

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
16:21:37,001 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.6.Final-redhat-1
16:21:38,802 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.1.5.Final-redhat-1
16:21:39,088 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) starting
16:21:48,992 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
16:21:49,033 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-4) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.13.GA-redhat-1
16:21:49,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:21:49,307 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Remoting version 3.3.4.Final-redhat-1
16:21:49,553 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013371: Activating Security Subsystem
16:21:49,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:21:49,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:21:49,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
16:21:49,559 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
16:21:50,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
16:21:51,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
16:21:51,217 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013370: Current PicketBox version=4.1.1.Final-redhat-1
16:21:51,392 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:21:51,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.31.Final-redhat-1)
16:21:52,121 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:21:52,551 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
16:21:52,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver (version 1.2)
16:21:52,669 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver (version 7.0)
16:21:53,013 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-/0.0.0.0:8080
16:21:53,018 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/0.0.0.0:8080
16:21:53,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/PowerSTEPP_CS2XSTEPP]
16:21:53,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:21:54,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT" (runtime-name: "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT")
16:21:54,159 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\jboss-eap-6.4.0\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\deployments
16:21:55,333 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.4.Final-redhat-1
16:21:55,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/CS_AWD]
16:21:55,959 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MHC_CS2XMHC]
16:21:55,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
16:21:55,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0:4447
16:21:58,049 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015859: Deployed "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT" (runtime-name : "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT")
16:21:58,450 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:21:58,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:21:58,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) started in 25723ms - Started 202 of 240 services (59 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connected to server
[2017-07-21 04:22:05,975] Artifact csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
16:22:06,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war")
16:27:06,760 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS013412: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war")]'
16:27:06,766 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: "JBAS013487: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability"
16:27:16,775 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS013413: Timeout after [5000] seconds waiting for service container stability while finalizing an operation. Process must be restarted. Step that first updated the service container was 'deploy' at address '[("deployment" => "csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war")]'
[2017-07-21 04:27:17,172] Artifact csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-07-21 04:27:17,172] Artifact csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war: java.lang.Exception: JBAS013487: Operation timed out awaiting service container stability
16:28:42,450 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry awdaft.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/AWDImageWindow-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,451 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry AWDImageWindow.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/AWDImageWindow-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,452 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry AWDImageWindowMSG_en_US.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/AWDImageWindow-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,452 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jh.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/AWDImageWindow-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,453 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry SnowBound.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/AWDImageWindow-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,454 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry AWDEncoding.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/AWDImageWindow-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,574 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry DefAnalyst.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/jdadminJobs-3.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,639 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry com.ibm.mq.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/mq-6.0.2.10.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,642 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry connector.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/mq-6.0.2.10.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,647 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jta.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/mq-6.0.2.10.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,654 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,680 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,680 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,681 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry serializer.jar in /D:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
16:28:42,914 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'moduleName=groovy-all' for service type 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule'
16:28:42,915 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'moduleVersion=2.4.4' for service type 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule'
16:28:42,916 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'extensionClasses=org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.ScriptExtensions,org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods,org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SqlGroovyMethods,org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods,org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.XmlGroovyMethods' for service type 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule'
16:28:42,916 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'staticExtensionClasses=org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.ScriptStaticExtensions' for service type 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule'
16:28:42,918 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,918 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,919 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,920 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,922 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,923 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,924 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,924 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,924 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,924 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,925 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,925 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,925 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,983 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,983 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,983 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,984 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,985 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,985 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,985 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,985 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$Text' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,986 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,986 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$Wadl' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,987 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,987 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,987 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,987 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,988 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,989 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter'
16:28:42,989 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$Wadl' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,990 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,990 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,990 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,991 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,991 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,991 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,992 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General' for service type 'javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader'
16:28:42,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$TypeFromStringEnum' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
16:28:42,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$TypeValueOf' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
16:28:42,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$TypeFromString' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
16:28:42,994 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$StringConstructor' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
16:28:42,995 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringReaderProviders$DateProvider' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
16:28:42,995 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.JAXBStringReaderProviders$RootElementProvider' for service type 'com.sun.jersey.spi.StringReaderProvider'
16:28:43,000 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
16:29:04,245 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: csWeb-2.1.17.6-SNAPSHOT.war) in 117461ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're missing some dependencies, or those dependencies are not loaded properly because they conflict with global libraries JBoss preloads.

Comment: I could able to deploy and run the application successfully outside IntelliJ. I could see the problem only when I try to start from IntelliJ IDE. Any clue now?